# (K)Ubuntu 23.10 Completely remove bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, reset

I have a bluetooth headset that was able to connect to my pc (Kubuntu 23.10). I disconnected the device and switched to win 11 (dual boot) and connected to windows bluetooth. After a restart win11 and ubuntu could not connect any longer to the device (it was not shown in the bluetooth available devices list). In win 11 I could solve the problem by deleting the entry of the device in the registry (can find and connect to the headset again).

In ubuntu I tried the commands
bluetoothctl -> remove MA:CA:DD:RE:SS (as suggested by [How can I remove a Bluetooth device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840464/how-can-i-remove-a-bluetooth-device))
which did not help (also with pc reboot no device is seen)

After this I removed a folder in /var/lib/bluetooth/controllerMAC/cache that had the same name as the mac address of the device. After a restart the headset is still not showing up in the list of e.g. bluetoothctl -> scan or the graphical list in the settings menu.

Is there a way to completely remove the device information (hard reset as If the device never paired with my pc) similar to the win11 solution? Or is there something obvious that should be done to be able to connect to the device again?

Note that this problem is different to [bluetoothctl - can't pair device after removing it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162457/bluetoothctl-cant-pair-device-after-removing-it) as the device does not even show up